# Session open but I am not getting access token Android FB SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am trying to retrieve the access token from the Facebook session with this code.

```
Session.openActiveSession(this,true,new Session.StatusCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

            if(state.isOpened())
            if (exception == null)
            {
              Log.v("Token",session.getAccessToken());
              .....
```

However I am not getting the access token. This is the result being returned

```
{Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[basic_info]}, appId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have you entered the **keyhash** in the App Settings? Generate a hash using the standard code provided by facebook:

   ```
   PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("<your_package_name>",  PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

   for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
   {
       MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
       md.update(signature.toByteArray());
       Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
   }
   ```
2. Double-check the **package name** in the App Settings.

---

**UPDATE** (another possible solution)

Override `onActivityResult` and call-

```
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: @JohnAlexander How did you get it working? because I have already done the above two solutions

Comment: @JohnAlexander please help me how you did that .